# Weather Widget/API

Tags: html, javascript, api, widgets

I am developing a website and am looking for an easy piece of code that I can add to a webpage that will display the weather for today and also for the next 5 days for a given location (Wellington, New Zealand).

I have fund some resources on-line, yet I am looking for a horizontal weather display, rather than a vertical display.

What is the easiest to implement and what do people recommend?

I would prefer a piece of code to just copy/paste into a HTML page, but if an API exists, that is easy to use, then I may look into using that.

**UPDATE**

I have found the following link that has the information that I am looking for: http://www.wunderground.com/q/zmw:00000.1.93436

Here is a screenshot of what I am wanting to display on my own webpage:

http://canning.co.nz/WeatherExample.jpg

Can I please have some help to input the correct code into a HTML document to display this information shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options that will get you rolling within a few minutes.  Unfortunately, you may not find all of the features you're looking for (as far as layout and functionality are both concerned) in one location...

- Weather Underground has Widgets for current conditions, two-day forecasts, tropical weather, and a myriad of others.  There are a variety of layouts you can choose from, and their two-day forecast sticker best matches your specifications for a horizontal widget with forecast data.  WU is generally very reliable and trustworthy weather resource.

  Link: http://www.wunderground.com/stickers/
- AccuWeather has a nice widget that displays current conditions, a
  4-day forecast, and a radar.  The radar is generally pretty
  unreliable and overly sensitive when it comes to snowfall, in my
  experience.  Still though, the data presented is very thorough.  I'm not seeing a good horizontal display on there, but there are some thinner vertical ones at least.

  Link: http://netweather.accuweather.com/adcbin/netweather_v2/signup-page1.asp

Comment: Thanks Hyper. Can you please look at my updated question.

Comment: @user22707 For the scope of what you want to do, I think you'll be limited to the stickers that Weather Underground has provided for quick and easy copying/pasting.  They do have an API [here](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/) that you can use if you really need such a robust dataset, but it will require some coding to implement and it is not free to use in a public setting.  After some more searching it seems that they can also create custom stickers for you, for a fee.